# Audio pitch drop with external interface

Tags: 16.04, sound, ubuntu-mate

Ubuntu Mate 16.04.

I'm using a USB Focusrite Scarlett 2i2 as my audio interface. Occasionally, I'll do something (ie Start a game from steam, join a voice channel in discord, switch out of a video game, open spotify, seemingly random things, nothing I can pin down at least) and the audio will pitch down by an octave or two. On EVERYTHING. A restart fixes it, though honestly I haven't tried the simpler unplug/replug yet. I'm just flabbergasted that it happens at all and was wondering if anyone knew of a rhyme or reason for it.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue with my Mixer/USB audio interface (Allen & Heath ZEDi 10FX).
Some searching led me to [this thread](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=229918) and then [this thread](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=32757#c64), both on the Chromium buglist.

This led me to add the following line the PulseAudio daemon config file `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf`:

```
default-sample-rate = 48000
```

Then kill the server with:

```
killall pulseaudio
```

Alternatively you can use:

```
pulseaudio --kill
```

This has, so far, solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely old, however I was able to find a fix to the problem. I am running POP!_OS, so it's similar enough. Under the Sound settings there should be an option to select analog input/output and digital input/output. You would want to select the digital option.

Outer Wilds and Red Faction Guerilla were both pitch shifted a whole step down. Switching the Sound settings to digital seems to have fixed the problem and even reduce frame-rate drops. It seems to be an issue with how proton communicates with the analog interface.